# What character encoding are ODBC datasources?

Tags: odbc

Specifically, what character encoding does `SQLDataSources` use?

On my Windows 7 machine (set to New Zealand English) it seems to use CP1252.  I can't find any mention of character encodings in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some experimentation and determined that data source names are in unicode. `SQLDataSources` gives you the name converted to the system code page, replacing characters that can't be converted with '?'.  This is about as useful as you might expect.  The undocumented function `SQLDataSourcesW` gives the name encoded in UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of database you use. For PostgreSQL I use `SET client_encoding to <encoding>;` after connecting do database. For Informix there is Client Encoding option available on Environment tab. For Oracle I use `NLS_LANG` environment setting.